# Many to many field with extra fields in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: Purchase and Product, in the Purchase model I have some fields and among them a many to many referencing the Product, but for each product inserted in the purchase I need to add a status field, price and quantity and I have no idea how I could do this. Later I need to change these fields and I also need to have the option of adding more products, changing a product or excluding it from the purchase.

**Purchase**

```
 class Purchase(models.Model):
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created At"), default=timezone.now)
     request_date = models.DateField(_("Request Date"), default=date.today)
     obs = models.TextField(_("Observation"))
     status = models.CharField(_("Status"), choices=STATUS, default="Pending", max_length=8)
     products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name=_("Products"))
     approval_date = models.DateField(_("Approval Date"), blank=True, null=True)`
```

**Product**

```
 class Product(models.Model):
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
     code = models.CharField(_("Code"), max_length=30)
     un = models.CharField(_("Measurement Unit"), max_length=30)
     description = models.TextField(_("Description"))`
```

I've tried to create a PurchaseProduct model but I couldn't make it work properly.

**PurchaseProduct**

```
 class PurchaseProduct(models.Model):
     purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     quantity = models.DecimalField(_("Quantity"), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
     price = models.DecimalField(_("Price"), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
     status = models.CharField(_("Status"), choices=STATUS, default="Pending", max_length=8)`
```

**Serializers**

```
class PurchaseProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Product.objects.all(), source="product", write_only=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseProduct
        fields = ("product_id", "quantity", "price", "status")


class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = PurchaseProductSerializer(many=True, source="purchaseproduct_set")

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        if data.get("request_date") and not retroactive_date(data["request_date"]):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"request_date": "A data da requisição não pode ser retroativa."}
            )
        if data.get("approval_date") and not retroactive_date(data["approval_date"]):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"approval_date": "A data da aprovação não pode ser retroativa."}
            )

        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop("purchaseproduct_set")

        if len(set((product_data["product"],) for product_data in products_data)) != len(
            products_data
        ):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"products": "Não é permitido produtos repetidos."}
            )
        
        purchase = Purchase.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for product_data in products_data:
            product = product_data["product"]
            quantity = product_data["quantity"]
            price = product_data["price"]
            status = product_data["status"]
            PurchaseProduct.objects.create(
                purchase=purchase, product=product, quantity=quantity, price=price, status=status
            )

        return purchase

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop("purchaseproduct_set", None)

        if products_data:
            if hasattr(instance, "purchaseproduct_set"):
                for purchase_product in instance.purchaseproduct_set.all():
                    for product_data in products_data:
                        status = product_data.get("status")
                        quantity = product_data.get("quantity")
                        price = product_data.get("price")

                        if purchase_product.product == product_data.get("product"):
                            if status and purchase_product.status != status:
                                purchase_product.status = status
                            if quantity and purchase_product.quantity != quantity:
                                purchase_product.quantity = quantity
                            if price and purchase_product.price != price:
                                purchase_product.price = price

                            purchase_product.save()

        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)

        instance.save()

        return instance
```

**Views**

```
class PurchaseListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = []
    ordering_fields = []
    filterset_fields = []
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class PurchaseProductListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = []
    ordering_fields = []
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        purchase_pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return PurchaseProduct.objects.filter(purchase=purchase_pk)
```

Comment: Your `Product` has no price?

Comment: Looks like your model setup is OK, except you don't need `products` field under `Purchase` any more, because you have a separate `PurchaseProduct` model. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem there is no price because it is a purchase requisition and the approver needs to analyze each product and see what price is being quoted

Comment: @EzonZhao with the PurchaseProduct model I can't edit the products, delete or add more later, could it be an error in the views/serializers?

Comment: I've added serializers and views to the question, currently I can only change price and quantity